# Ionic React - Binding element 'selected' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ionic-framework, controller, react-hooks

I know there are other questions out there for this, but it's been difficult to abstract towards my particular problem. This is a form meant to input account signup values to store into a db.

"selected" which you'll find below comes with the above 7031 error. It might also have to do with the "control" feature alongside the Controller element (or function, whatever its called), so I attached above code with the values the "selected" is referring to.

Hope this helps solve the issue, greatly appreciated.

```
function chooseInitValues(){
    var initialValues = {};
    if (value){
      initialValues = {
        firstname: "",
        lastname: "",
        dateofbirth: "",
        shopownerhomeaddress: "",
        zipcode: "",
        city: "",
        state: "",
        phonenumber: "",
        last4digitsofssn: "",
    }
  }
      
    
    return initialValues; 

var initValues = chooseInitValues();
const { control, handleSubmit, formState, reset, errors } = useForm({
  defaultValues: { ...initValues },
  mode: "onChange"
});


    return (
    <IonPage>
        <IonHeader>
            <IonToolbar>
              <IonTitle>
                <IonTitle>Become a Seller</IonTitle>
              </IonTitle>
            </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <IonContent className="ion-padding">
            <IonCol text-center>
              <p><strong>Complete the application to become a seller.</strong></p>
            </IonCol>
        
        
        <IonList>
          <IonItem>
            <h2>Signer Uppers Personal Information</h2>
          </IonItem>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} style={{padding: 0}}></form>
              
              <IonItem>
                <IonLabel>First Name</IonLabel>
                <Controller
                as={
                  <IonInput placeholder='empty'></IonInput>
                }
                control={control}
                onChangeName="onIonChange"
                onChange={([selected]) => {
                console.log("First Name", selected.detail.value);
                return selected.detail.value;
                }}
                name="firstname"                
                rules={{
                required: true,
                }}
              />
              </IonItem>
```

Comment: Looking at the examples on https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/select, it appears it should be `onIonChange` rather than `onChange`.  And the parameter should be `e.target.value`. But I haven't use ionic so I could be off base.

Comment: I will check this, for now I just did {([selected]: any)} => { and it worked, removed the errors. Now I'm just trying to figure out why the Submit button is not enabling when i fill out all the fields

Answer (score 1):

doesn't look like you are using the latest version of react hook form?
Also you don't need to do all the controller, is for the IonInput.
Not sure what you are trying to do with `selected`?

This code is working for me

```
<IonItem>
  <IonLabel>Description</IonLabel>
  <IonInput
    type="text"
    name={"description"}
    placeholder="Description"
    ref={register({ required: "Description Is Required" })}
  ></IonInput>
</IonItem>
```